# Giving zombie villagers multiple apples or curing them multiple times?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If you give a zombie villager in Minecraft more than one golden apple, will it give you better trades than if you only give it one golden apple? And if you cure it more than once, will it give you better trades than if you only cured it once?
If so, how many cures can you do before it won't do better trades?

I am playing on Bedrock Edition but on a Java Edition Server, so if they are different then please specify both if you can.

Comment: What do you mean with "how many trades can you do before it won't do better trades"?

Comment: @pinckerman Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, giving more than one golden apple has no effect.
However, performing multiple dezombifications results in better trades.

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager#Curing):

> The newly-cured villager, if it had a profession prior to being zombified, offers a large discount on trades to the player who administered the cure. The discount from curing a zombie villager persists permanently.

> If a villager is cured more than once, **its discounts increase until the price reaches the minimum of one emerald**.

As an extra:

> Villagers around the cured villager are also affected. In Bedrock Edition, villagers in a range of 16 blocks in a cube surrounding the cured villager also offer a small discount proportional to the number of cured villagers (up to 10).